# Issue on Printing Array With HTML <pre> element

Tags: php

I am trying to print_r an wrapped in html `<pre></pre>` tags using flowing line

> `echo '<pre>',print_r($data),'</pre>';`

at

```
$data = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM data";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $data[] = $row;
    }
    $result->free();
}
echo '<pre>',print_r($data),'</pre>';
```

but what I am getting is following output with `<pre>` tag at beginning and  `1</pre>` at the end of the `print_r` function!

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [age] => 35
            [name] => Ben
            [sex] => M
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [age] => 64
            [name] => Rose
            [sex] => F
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [age] => 31
            [name] => Mar
            [sex] => F
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [age] => 14
            [name] => Mollan
            [sex] => M
        )

)            1</pre>
```

can you please let me know what is that `1` at the end o pre? why this is happening? and how I can fix this?

> Update

For what ever reason Stack overflow input box doesn't show the  `1</pre>` at the end of array result! I am going to put image here for reference, as well.

[image]

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have an older version of PHP or magic quotes enabled?

Comment: Hi Brian, I installed MAMP few month ago, so I do not think it is old! but about magic quotes enabled, I am not sure , how can I check it?

Comment: MAMP should should have a way to load the phpinfo() output in your browser.   Once loaded in browser hit <ctrl> + F to bring up search box and type magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to return the output of print_r as a string by passing TRUE.

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, TRUE) . '</pre>';
```

personally printf looks a little nicer with this

```
printf("<pre>%s</pre>",print_r($data,TRUE));
```

reference here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: Thanks jbrahy but the pre still sitting there!

Comment: Is your page using the HTML content type? not parsing <pre> sounds like content-type text/plain

Comment: Got it thanks. I was using json content type header thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
print_r($data, true);
```

the second parameter is whether you want to output or return the printed array.  By default it is set to false so it will print out in place, returning 1 for success.

Since you are using `print_r` in line (concatenating it) you need to have it returned as a string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';`

Answer (score -1):

The issue is in your echo statement you're using comas instead of periods to contact the echo string.   Should read like this:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($data) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks Brian Bolli but the pre still sitting there!